# Conflicting flex boxes in Vuetify layout components

Tags: vuejs2, flexbox, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify in a project, where I am unable to get a component to fill the remaining height of the screen.

It's a conflicting flexbox issue between the `v-main` & `v-container` components, because if i remove the `v-main` component then **Row-2** successfully grows to fill screen height, however removing the `v-main` breaks the responsiveness in the rest of the layout.

https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/LYZmOzy

What needs to be done to get **Row 2** to fill the rest of the available height of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to the css:

```
.v-main__wrap{
  display: flex;
}
```

That way your v-container will actually stretch to fill the space of the v-main.

https://codepen.io/ZachHaber/pen/NWrLXeV

Answer (score 1):

Add this style rule to give the container 100% height:

```
.v-application .flex-nowrap{
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying the following will also work

```
.v-main__wrap{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```